# Callback must be a function. Received null / socket.io / set interval

Tags: node.js, socket.io

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function.
>   Received null

I have a set interval to call a player check function
to return to a socket an answer

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  setInterval(queue.searching(), 1000);
  //ADD PLAYER TO QUEUE
  socket.on('addPlayer-Queue', (result) => {
      sessionMap.set(socket.id,socket);
      queue.addPlayer(new Player({
        id: result.id,
        name: result.name,
        mmr: result.mmr
      }, socket.id));
      /*
      console.log(queue);
      console.log(sessionMap.all());*/
  socket.emit('match', matches) 
  });


});
```

my class queue.js

```
const {Match, configurePlayersForNewMatch} = require('./Match');
// Queue class is a queue system with players.
class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.players = [];
  }

  // addPlayers add multiple players into queue
  addPlayers(players) {

      this.players = this.players.concat(players);
  }

  // addPlayer adds a single player into queue
  addPlayer(player) {
    if(!this.players.find(p => p.id == player.id)){
      this.players.push(player);
    }
  }

  // removePlayers remove multiple players from queue
  removePlayers(players) {
    players.forEach(p => {
      this.removePlayer(p);
    });
  }

  // removePlayer removes a single player from queue
  removePlayer(player) {
    this.players = this.players.filter(p => p.id !== player.id)
  }

  // getPlayers return players that are currently on queue
  getPlayers() {
    return this.players;
  }
  getRandomPlayer() {
    return this.players[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.players.length)];
  }

  calculateLessThanPercentage(player) {
    return 5 / 100 * player.mmr + player.mmr 
  }

  calculateGreaterThanPercentage(player) {
    return player.mmr - 5 / 100 * player.mmr
  }


  searching() {
    const firstPlayer = this.getRandomPlayer();
    console.log(firstPlayer);
    const secondPlayer = this.players.find(
      playerTwo =>
        playerTwo.mmr < this.calculateLessThanPercentage(firstPlayer) &&
        playerTwo.mmr > this.calculateGreaterThanPercentage(firstPlayer) &&
        playerTwo.id != firstPlayer.id
    );

    if (!secondPlayer) {
      return null;
    }
    if(matchedPlayers){
    const matchedPlayers = [firstPlayer, secondPlayer];
    this.removePlayers(matchedPlayers);
    configurePlayersForNewMatch(matchedPlayers);
    }
  }

}
```

and my class match:

```
const uuid = require("uuid");
const assert = require('assert');
const sessionMap = require('./SessionMap');
// Match class is a single game Match structure
class Match {
    constructor(players) {
      this.id = uuid.v4().toString();
      this.players = players;
      this.isActive = false;;
    }

    startMatch(){
      this.isActive = true;
    }
    stopMatch(){
      this.isActive = false;
    }
  }
  const getMatchConfigurationFor = player => {
    console.log(player);
  }
  const configurePlayersForNewMatch = (matchedPlayers) => matchedPlayers.forEach(player =>
    sessionMap.get(player.socketid)
        .broadcast.to(player.socketid)
        .emit('match',
                      getMatchConfigurationFor(player)));

  module.exports = {Match, configurePlayersForNewMatch};
```

basically i take 2 players from my queue and send the player a response with data to populate the front end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval(queue.searching(), 1000);
```

Should be:

```
setInterval(queue.searching.bind(queue), 1000);
// setInterval(() => queue.searching(), 1000);
```

You have to pass a function to `setInterval`, you're passing the return value of `queue.searching` which is not a function, but `null` in that particular case.

Comment: `queue.searching.bind(queue);` or `() => queue.searching()`

Comment: Could you tell me if I will have problem on my emit?

since I didn't pass any socket for my class match?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'broadcast' of undefined i got this

Comment: You have to check that the session exists, in the `sessionMap`
`const session = sessionMap.get(player.socketid);
if(session)
        session.broadcast.to(player.socketid)`

Comment: Oops I can take just one more question about design pattern

do you find it interesting to apply singleton and factories

on this occasion?

Comment: I don't think it really matters, whatever you feel more confortable with should be fine. And it is a bit out of the scope of this question :P